# Are there any best practice for making question and answers googlable?

Tags: discussion, google

When a question is asked or answered on Stack Overflow (or any other Stack Exchange sites) I considered the fact that it can be found by Google to be very important.

Google has been my main entry point to Stack Overflow.

When faced with a question I would normally:

1. Google keyword which I believe would give me the answer. If unsuccessful:
2. Ask on Stack Overflow.

When posting a question should I include (key-)words in the question, which I used in my Google search for the answer or is that a waste of time?

Will it help improving Google search results to have tags repeated in the question/answer text?

Comment: This may be FAQ-able. Comments?

Answer (score 4):

Keywords would be helpful, but don't make a comma-delimited list. For instance, if you are receiving an Exception, it is helpful to copy/paste the Exception description into the title. Such as, "Exception: Cannot convert to int from char using function CharToInt()". More than likely, someone will search for the same thing which helps drive the traffic to SO. However, the goal should be to write quality questions and answers which will lead to good Google traffic because Google's search software is smart enough to determine quality - not to make SO into a link farm.

Answer (score 2):

Just be as clear and thorough as possible. Make sure you've run a spell-checker and double check your grammar.

In an answer provide links to sources (MSDN, Javadoc, etc.), quote the relevant part of the source, add your own summary.

In a question include the code, use the *appropriate* tags. There's no need to repeat the tags in the question title as Stack Overflow adds that for you. Make your title a question.